# Displaying image in android webview for an html file which is not saved

Tags: android, webview

I have a `webview` created and below is the code to it . At the same time I have created a html file and stored in the the string variable .

I wanted to display an image which is in my `mipmap` folder .

Found a few solutions but all of them were for a saved html file and the image was residing in assert folder .

PS : How would I mention the path for the image source such that it displays the image named `abc.jpeg` which is located in `mipmap` folder .

**abc.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.displaydetails);

    WebView page = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ww_data_area);
    String text = "<html><head>"
            + "<style type=\"text/css\">body{background-color: #fefefe;}"
            + "</style></head>"
            + "<body>"
            + "<p align=\"justify\">"
            +"<b>Please work :P </b>"
            + getString(R.string.LU1)
            + "<img src=\"" + R.mipmap.abc +
            "\" width=\"50px\" alt=\"Hello\">"
            + "</p>"
            + "</body></html>";

    page.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly after lots of experiments found an answer from one of the SO question itself, which was more or less similar problem like mine .

page.loadDataWithBaseURL did the work for me .

```
   String text = "<html><head>"
            + "<style type=\"text/css\">body{background-color: #fefefe;}"
            + "</style></head>"
            + "<body>"
            + "<p align=\"justify\">"
            + "<img src=\"splashscreen.jpeg\"/>"
            + "</p>"
            + "</body></html>";
    //page.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
    page.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",text, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```